# Blue water and plastic pieces always stuck in the screen in faucets

Tags: plumbing

Sometimes the water in the toilet and the faucets are blue and the screen in the sinks are always getting clogged with small plastic pieces....I do not know what is going on with that..and the water , when not blue is very cloudy no matter how long i let it run first....Help me please...Because my landlord seems to think there is no problem and I believe there is....I can not even stand to drink it...taste funny....

Comment: Don't drink blue water, cloudy water or water with plastic pieces in it. Something is very wrong.

Comment: Is your hot water not lasting as long as it should?

Comment: Where are you? Well? City supply?  Cistern?

Comment: Pour some of the water in a clear glass. Scoop up some of the plastic. Take them and show the landlord. Drink bottled water only. Cook with bottled water only.